# IE 11 +In glyphicon-calendar when select the date of the next month mirror image comes

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, datepicker

In the IE 11 , date controller when i open the date controller and select the date of the next month in that case the mirror image comes.

Please note that this image comes only one time when i open the controller and changes the date to next month only.

[image]

Please help !

Comment: Which date picker are you using ?

Comment: Bootstrap Glyphicon 's calender controller i am using. This problem is specially for the IE